# Parsing HTML to Hashmap in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java app with the google voice api, and a method to get SMS data and convos returns an entire html page like this

http://pastebin.com/tjZeHERa

I wrote an SMSMessage class where it recieves the HTML as a String and will parse the first message data between the  tags, but it uses an arrayList instead of a Hashmap.

```
package gv;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SMSMessage {

   protected String id;
   protected String phoneNumber;
   protected String displayNumber;
   protected String message;
   protected String startTime;
   protected String displayStartDateTime;
   protected boolean isRead;
   protected String messageText;

public SMSMessage(String x){

    parse(TruncateFirstMessage(x));
    parseresponse(x);

}
    public String TruncateFirstMessage(String xml){

       int firstbracket = xml.indexOf("{");
       //int secondbracket = xml.indexOf("{", firstbracket - 1);
       int thirdbracket = xml.indexOf("}");
       int fourthbracket = xml.indexOf("}", thirdbracket - 1);
        return xml.substring(firstbracket, fourthbracket);   
    }
    private void parseresponse(String init){
        String trimmeds1 = init.substring(init.indexOf("<html><![CDATA[)"));
        String trimmeds2 = init.substring(trimmeds1.indexOf(phoneNumber));
        Scanner s = new Scanner(trimmeds1);




    }

    private  void parse(String init){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(init);
        ArrayList<String> parsed = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.useDelimiter("[},:{]");
        String temp1 = "";
        int count = 0;
            while (s.hasNext()){

              String n = s.next();
                if (!n.equals("")){
                     count++;
                    String removequotes = n.replace("\"", "");


                      parsed.add(removequotes);  }
                }
            id = parsed.get(3);
            phoneNumber = parsed.get(5);
            displayNumber = parsed.get(7);
            startTime = parsed.get(9);
            displayStartDateTime = parsed.get(11) + ":" + parsed.get(12);
            isRead = Boolean.parseBoolean(parsed.get(21));
            messageText = parsed.get(29);

          }

    public String toString(){

        return getClass().getSimpleName() + " [ " + "id = " + id + ", phoneNumber = " + phoneNumber + ", isRead = " + isRead + ", messageText = " + messageText + ", displayStartDateTime = " + displayStartDateTime + " ]";

    }
}
```

this will return a pretty long arrayList, like
[messages, 0609dc2d10f365600fc48372fe3122a7ba3147fa, id, 0609dc2d10f365600fc48372fe3122a7ba3147fa, phoneNumber, +17654260681, displayNumber, (765) 426-0681, startTime, 1365514638712, displayStartDateTime, 4/9/13 9, 37 AM, displayStartTime, 9, 37 AM, relativeStartTime, 40 minutes ago, note, , isRead, true, isSpam, false, isTrash, false, star, false, messageText, hi, labels, [inbox, sms, all], type, 11, children, ]

and then I get a specific element and assign it to a field.

How would I replace the arrayList with a HashMap where the keys would be "relativeStartTime" and the value would be the next int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is lovely.

First, it's not HTML, it's XML.

Second, the data you want is JSON formatted.

So you have an XML payload containing JSON Data. Marvelous.

What you should do is strip of the XML tags, leaving the JSON payload whole. Then run the JSON payload through one of the many JSON parsers available on the internet. You could use an XML parser for this task as well, but it's simple enough XML that you probably don't need to learn one of those toolkits as well.

The JSON parsers are quick and easy to use, and will give you pretty much exactly what you're looking for.